# About the boundary of "broad"

Tags: discussion

I know that "too broad" was intensively discussed in the past, I've read many threads and deduced that way the main features of broad questions.
The theory seemed to work pretty well, at least until yesterday, when I noticed [**this question**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/14960/3-planks-1-nail/14970?noredirect=1#comment46095_14970): it basically asks you to build a tough triangle out of three planks and one nail; no additional information, no restrictions (except that you can't be violent, but it isn't a very tight limitation).
Of course, the problem has received a large amount of different answers, all valid and creative.
I expected that post to be flagged as too broad, but no, it was protected!
Just to be clear, I have nothing against that question nor its author, I'm just wondering why that puzzle is still open, while many similar (I mean, same features) puzzles were insta-closed in the past. Is there any particular reason to keep it open, aside from the views, the upvotes and its general popularity?

Comment: Note: Protected questions can absolutely be closed; protection just helps mitigate low-quality answers. Don't worry about VTCing protected questions. If you see something popular but you deem it close-worthy, feel free to VTC anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The question under discussion has [since been closed](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/14960/3-planks-1-nail) (although it looks close to re-opening...).